# Целостность файловой системы и базы данных (транзакции фс)

Tags: база-данных, файловая-система, транзакции

Есть сайт, на который можно загружать разные файлы. Информация о файле сохраняется в бд, а сам файл в фс. И есть некоторая логика по работе с файлами. Например:

```
начинаем транзакцию
работаем с бд
нужно изменить название файла
изменяем название файла
работаем дальше с бд
возникает непредвиденная ошибка, при которой нужно все откатить
откатываем транзакцию
```

При этом файл остается переименованным.
Собственно интересует вопрос: Есть ли какой то софт, для возможности проводить транзакции в файловой системе.
Или как правильно организовать работу с файлами, что бы в таких ситуациях можно было, как-то, это все красиво сделать?

Comment: полной синхронности вряд ли удастся добиться. А переименовывать файлы вообще не надо. Именуйте их по id с которыми они в БД

Comment: Кроме переименования может быть запись нового контента, или вообще удаление, например.

Comment: проще сделать скрипт синхронизации, который по крону будет искать файлы о которых БД не знает или о которых знает, но их нет. либо придется делать систему двойной фиксации транзакций. пишем файл под временным именем. sync. пишем в БД факт создания, текущее и ожидаемое имя, commit, переименовываем файл в правильное имя, sync, апдейтим статус транзакции в БД, commit. Но все равно как в БД есть система отката при перезапуске БД, так и при рестарте сервера надо будет брать из БД "подвешенные" транзакции и накатывать/откатывать их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже если вы найдёте транзакционную файловую систему (почему бы нет, на `fuse` много странных вещей сделано) - то тогда перед вами в полный рост встанет куда более увлекательный вопрос - а как их вообще коммитить? Вы ведь можете упасть после коммита базы и до коммита ФС (или наоборот) и получите несогласованное состояние в целом.

И это, в общем-то, единственный осмысленный пример, при котором хранение файла как blob в базе может быть целесообразно. Смотреть надо на сложность и стоимость хранения файлов в базе или сопровождения их отдельно, и не забыть учесть как всё бекапить.

Во всяком случае с доступными не только вашей системе файлами вы транзакционно работать не сможете. Если доступ есть только у вас - то уже извращаться можно. Например, вместо переименовывания файла вы делаете хардлинк на него в новое место, а в базе ведёте список всех актуальных файлов. Для изменения файла - копируете файл и изменяете только копию (да, вам для этого придётся изменить имя файла как побочный эффект). При удалении файла - вовсе не трогаете файл. Для всех этих действий вам потребуется фоновый процесс сборщика мусора, который будет подчищать старые файлы, отсутствующие в базе. Кстати, учтите при написании сборщика мусора, чтобы он не пытался удалять файлы ещё открытых транзакций.

Чтобы не переизобретать всю машинерию изоляции транзакций - лучше сделать отдельную табличку имеющихся файлов в имеющейся базе и ссылаться на неё через foreign key и в ней же хранить действительное текущее имя файла на диске (но вот использовать primary key в качестве имени файла вы сможете только если файлы не надо изменять, а только создавать или удалять).